# New version of SDL doesn't allow me to use SDL_image

Tags: c++, sdl

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxu0l.png)

I created another 2 projects. One on **SDL 2.0.8 and SDL_image 2.0.3**. There is code on which I tested that:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <cstdio>

SDL_Window * window = NULL;
SDL_Surface * windowSurface = NULL;
SDL_Renderer * renderer = NULL;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        printf("Cannot init SDL. Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(-1);
    }
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Client", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot create window. Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(-1);
    }
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    if (renderer = NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot create renderer. Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(-1);
    }
    //Init PNG loading
    if (!(IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG) & IMG_INIT_PNG))
    {
        printf("Cannot init PNG loading. Error: %s\n", IMG_GetError());
        exit(-1);
    }
    windowSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

On this setup I wasn't able to run it, I got an error.

Second project had **SDL 2.0.5** and **SDL_image 2.0.0** and it **worked.**

Why I cant use the newest versions of SDL and SDL_image although SDL_image is compatible with SDL 2.0.8 ?

Comment: And what code did you wrote?

Comment: "I suppose that is not my fault" - probably wrong. A) *You* changed something. Stuff broke - your fault. B) More often than not, the error you are looking for is *in code you wrote*, not the library, the compiler or the OS.  Your first assumption should always be "I did something wrong" and then you should ask "what did *I* do wrong".

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that I did something wrong but after changing to lower versions i saw that it is working. That is strange for me.

Comment: Something in the question is wrong - `SDL_LoadFile_RW` first appeared in SDL 2.0.6, so it can't 'work' in 2.0.0, but it should be in 2.0.8. The error caused by the fact that your version of SDL_image depends on newer SDL. There may be many reasons - e.g. you think you've updated the library, but used wrong architecture (or don't have dependencies) and (older) systemwide library is used instead.

Comment: I'm using SDL2-devel-2.0.8-VC.zip from libsdl.org and SDL2_image-devel-2.0.3-VC.zip also from libsdl.org

Answer (score 1):

this say you have a mismatch between the headers, .lib and .dll files you are using. Make sure you delete all the old ones from all the hidey places in your paths

use sysinternal procmon tool to see exactly where the dll is being loaded from

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that throwing all .dll files into Debug folder in my project. I was writing it in Visual Studio 2017 and in lower versions of SDL I didn't have to do that.